# How do Ruby Directories work?

Tags: ruby, io, stream, directory

`Dir`-s seem awkward as compared to `File`-s. Many of the methods are similar to `IO` methods, but a `Dir` doesn't inherit from `IO`. For example, `tell` in the `IO` docs reads:

> Returns the current offset (in bytes) of ios.

When `read`-ing and `tell`-ing through a normal `Dir`, I get large numbers like `346723732` and `422823816`. I was originally expecting these integers to be more "array-like" and just be a simple range.

- Are these the bytes of the files contained in the `Dir`?
- If not, is there any meaning to the numbers returned like `IO#tell`?
- Also why do `Dir`-s have an `open` and `close` function if they are not Streams?
- Is it still just as important to close a `Dir` as a normal `IO`?

Any general explanation of how a Ruby `Dir` works would be appreciated.

**update** Another confusing part: if `Dir`s are not `IO`s, why does [close](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-i-close) raise an `IOerror`?

> Closes the directory stream. Any further attempts to access dir will raise an IOError.

Also notice that in the documentation it considers it a "directory stream". So this brings up the question again of are they streams or not and if not, why the naming convention?

Comment: Whot? `Dir` is not inherited from `IO`. A directory is not an `IO` object, it is an organized structure of pointers to files. It has nothing to do with `IO`.

Comment: @Casper My mistake. I saw the similar terminology and assumed.

Comment: It happens. Just check out the docs, it should make everything quite clear: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-i-seek and http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-i-tell

Comment: @Casper and I have been reading the docs, the only reason I'm here is because I felt it wasn't explained well enough.

Comment: I was reading [this article](http://ruby.runpaint.org/files) and the author points out that although `Dir`s are not IOStreams, you can still create streams to them and hence can be opened and closed.

Comment: I think it's unfortunate that the `Dir` class uses the same terminology in its method calls as those of a real `IO` stream. In my opinion it is just a confusing naming convention. Directories are DEFINITIVELY not streams, and should not be thought of as such. The fact that the `Dir` class has methods that are named the same as in an `IO` object is just..well..confusing; as can be witnessed by them confusing you already :) So: they are NOT streams, they are NOT `IO`, they just use methods that are named the same.

Comment: The author of `Dir` seemed to have gotten the idea that `Dir` should be thought of as a "stream of file names". And that is the closest to a "stream" that I would be willing to go with this class. But it is definitively not a stream. It is just a collection of file names with a silly stream-like interface. Just not the best design. Thinking of it as an array would be much more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some IRC chat here's the conclusion I've come to:

#### The `Dir` object is NOT an `IO`

`Dir` Does not inherit from the IO class and is only readable. Still not sure why an `IOError` is raised on `#close`.

#### An opened `Dir` IS a stream however

> Objects of class Dir are directory streams representing directories in the underlying file system.

Also if you check the [source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/dir.c#L737-L757) for `Dir#close` You will see that it calls the C function `dirclose`. `man dirclose` prints:

> The  `closedir()`  function  closes  the directory stream associated with
>   `dirp`.  A successful call to `closedir()` also closes the underlying  file
>   descriptor  associated with `dirp`.  The directory stream descriptor `dirp`
>   is not available after this call.

...with `dirp` being a param.

So yes, instantiated `Dir`s **will** open a stream and yes, `Dir`s will use a file descriptor and need to be closed if you do not want to rely on garbage collection.

Big thanks to *injekt* and others on **#ruby-lang** irc!

Answer (score 3):

The docs for `Dir#tell` say:

```
Returns the current position in dir.
```

without specifying what the position means. What the returned value signifying is likely to vary based on the OS that you're using and possibly the type of the file system that contains the directory. That value should be treated as opaque, don't try to interpret it in any way. The only purpose it serves is for being able to send that value back to the OS such as by calling `Dir#seek`.

Directories are not just a giant file.  More typically they just map from a file name to information about where the data for the file is contained.

You should not (and as far as I'm aware cannot) write to directories yourself.

Comment: You've answered most of my questions already, but I've updated the question a bit the correct the assumption brought up by Casper.